# how to add multiple subject area in OTBI

Tags: oracle, cloud

I have added Workforce Management- Person Real Time and 
             Workforce Management- Worker Assignment Real Time creating report with some business field filter condition but i am getting error after adding Prefix as SET VARIABLE ENABLE_DIMENSIONALITY = 1; in advance tab.

how to do cross subject area without error in OTBI ?

Answer (score 0):

please check below code, it's working.

GO in the advance tab, paste it into the SQL section.

SO basically there is to subject area
1.  "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time"
2. "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"

```
    /* How to merge Two Subject Area */
**SET VARIABLE ENABLE_DIMENSIONALITY = 1;
SELECT 0 s_0,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time".
        "Assignment Event Details"."Assignment Number"
          s_1,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time".
        "Assignment Event Details"."Assignment Sequence"
          s_2,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time".
        "Assignment Event Details"."Assignment Status Type"
          s_3,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time".
        "Assignment Event Details"."Assignment Type"
          s_4,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time"."Worker".
        "Employee First Name"
          s_5,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time"."Worker".
        "Employee Last Name"
          s_6,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time".
        "Worker Assignment Details"."Assignment Sequence"
          s_7,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time".
        "Worker Assignment Details"."Assignment Status Type"
          s_8,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time".
        "Assignment Event"."Assignment Event Count"
          s_9,
       "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time".
        "Worker Assignment"."Assignment Count"
          s_10
  FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Event Real Time"
 WHERE ( ("Worker"."Employee Last Name" = 'Weasley')
        AND ("Worker"."Employee First Name" = 'George')
        AND ("Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time".
              "Worker Assignment Details"."Assignment Status Type" = 'Active'))**
```